# How to create slanted underline style

Tags: css

I'm trying to achieve this underline style using CSS. It needs to work on text with multiple lines. Has anyone got any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Please show the code what have you tried??

Comment: SO is not a code writing service, we help with written code, and users posting questions are supposed to make a proper research and an effort of their own, which you obviously haven't, providing a [_sample within the question_](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please do and come back with it, if you can't make it work. If anything is unclear, please reread [ask].

Answer (score 2):

Here is an idea that rely on [`box-decoration-break`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-decoration-break) and background coloration:

```css
p > span {
 background:
   linear-gradient(-225deg,#0000 10px,red 10px) bottom left,
   linear-gradient(-45deg ,#0000 10px,red 10px) bottom right;
 background-size: 60% 10px;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 padding: 0 15px 5px;
 -webkit-box-decoration-break: clone;
 box-decoration-break: clone; 
 
 font-size:25px;
 font-weight:bold;
}
```

```html
<p><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <br>consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc purus lectus, gravida in gravida non, consequat i</span></p>

<p><span>Lorem ipsum dolor</span></p>
```

Without `box-decoration-break` you can have a more supported way but will not tight to the text, it will simply consider the number of lines.

```css
p {
 background:
   repeating-linear-gradient(to bottom,#fff 0 calc(1.2em - 10px),transparent calc(1.2em - 10px) 1.2em),
   linear-gradient(-225deg,transparent 1.2em,red 0) bottom left/60% 1.2em,
   linear-gradient(-45deg ,transparent 1.2em,red 0) bottom right/60% 1.2em;
 background-repeat:repeat-y;
 padding:0 20px;
 line-height:1.2em;
 
 font-size:25px;
 font-weight:bold;
}
```

```html
<p><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <br>consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc purus lectus, gravida in gravida non, consequat i</span></p>

<p><span>Lorem ipsum dolor</span></p>
```

Answer (score -2):

Temani Afif has provided a clean way to implement this - if anything my answer is proving it is a lot more complex to achieve the same results in the way I did it.

Here is my suggestion:

```css
    * {
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    .example {
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 1248px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding: 20px;
        background-color: red;
        position: relative;
        display: -webkit-box;
        display: -moz-box;
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: -webkit-flex;
        display: flex;
        -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        flex-direction: row;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
    }

        .contain {
            padding: 20px;
            background-color: red;
            position: relative;
            display: -webkit-box;
            display: -moz-box;
            display: -ms-flexbox;
            display: -webkit-flex;
            display: flex;
            -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
            flex-direction: column;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: space-around;
        }

            h1 {
                text-align: center;
                font-size: 36px;
                line-height: 40px;
                position: relative;
                display: -webkit-box;
                display: -moz-box;
                display: -ms-flexbox;
                display: -webkit-flex;
                display: flex;
                -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
                flex-wrap: wrap;
                flex-direction: column;
                align-items: center;
                justify-content: space-around;
            }

                h1 span {
                    margin-bottom: 10px;
                    position: relative;
                    display: -webkit-box;
                    display: -moz-box;
                    display: -ms-flexbox;
                    display: -webkit-flex;
                    display: flex;
                    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
                    flex-wrap: wrap;
                    flex-direction: column;
                    align-items: center;
                    justify-content: space-around;
                }
                    h1 span .underline {
                        width: calc(100% - 20px);
                        height: 10px;
                        position: absolute;
                        top: 100%;
                        background-color: white;

                    }
                        h1 span .underline:before {
                            content: '';
                            width: 0px;
                            height: 0px;
                            position: absolute;
                            top: 0;
                            left: -10px;

                            background-color: transparent;
                            border-style: solid;
                            border-width: 5px;
                            border-color: transparent black black transparent; 
                        }
                        h1 span .underline:after {
                            content: '';
                            width: 0px;
                            height: 0px;
                            position: absolute;
                            top: 0;
                            right: -10px;

                            background-color: transparent;
                            border-style: solid;
                            border-width: 5px;
                            border-color: black transparent transparent black; 
                        }
```

```html
    <div class="example">
        <div class="contain">
            <h1>
                <span>Hello World<div class="underline"></div></span>
                <span>Hello Human<div class="underline"></div></span>
                <span>Hello Alien?<div class="underline"></div></span>
                <span>No, Hello AI!<div class="underline"></div></span>
            </h1>
            <div class="underline"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="contain">
            <h1>
                <span>Hello World<div class="underline"></div></span>
                <span>Hello Human<div class="underline"></div></span>
                <span>Hello Alien?<div class="underline"></div></span>
                <span>No, Hello AI!<div class="underline"></div></span>
            </h1>
            <div class="underline"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="contain">
            <h1>
                <span>Hello World<div class="underline"></div></span>
                <span>Hello Human<div class="underline"></div></span>
                <span>Hello Alien?<div class="underline"></div></span>
                <span>No, Hello AI!<div class="underline"></div></span>
            </h1>
            <div class="underline"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="contain">
            <h1>
                <span>Hello World<div class="underline"></div></span>
                <span>Hello Human<div class="underline"></div></span>
                <span>Hello Alien?<div class="underline"></div></span>
                <span>No, Hello AI!<div class="underline"></div></span>
            </h1>
            <div class="underline"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Create a div that will contain the colour of your underline, then produce a before and after to add your flicks.

If you utilise flex-box well you can get it to be the width of your title too.

### Edit

An implementation that will work across multiple lines - you will need to include the spans and underlines per line-break. I will have a go now to produce this without using the div with a class of underline.

Here I use jQuery to put the underlines in, you just need to break your heading into sections using the spans:

```js
    (function ($) {

        $( 'span' ).append( '<div class="underline"></div>' );

    })(jQuery);
```

```css
    * {
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    .example {
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 1248px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding: 20px;
        background-color: red;
        position: relative;
        display: -webkit-box;
        display: -moz-box;
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: -webkit-flex;
        display: flex;
        -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        flex-direction: row;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
    }

        .contain {
            padding: 20px;
            background-color: red;
            position: relative;
            display: -webkit-box;
            display: -moz-box;
            display: -ms-flexbox;
            display: -webkit-flex;
            display: flex;
            -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
            flex-direction: column;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: space-around;
        }

            h1 {
                text-align: center;
                font-size: 36px;
                line-height: 40px;
                position: relative;
                display: -webkit-box;
                display: -moz-box;
                display: -ms-flexbox;
                display: -webkit-flex;
                display: flex;
                -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
                flex-wrap: wrap;
                flex-direction: column;
                align-items: center;
                justify-content: space-around;
            }

                h1 span {
                    margin-bottom: 10px;
                    position: relative;
                    display: -webkit-box;
                    display: -moz-box;
                    display: -ms-flexbox;
                    display: -webkit-flex;
                    display: flex;
                    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
                    flex-wrap: wrap;
                    flex-direction: column;
                    align-items: center;
                    justify-content: space-around;
                }
                    h1 span .underline {
                        width: calc(100% - 20px);
                        height: 10px;
                        position: absolute;
                        top: 100%;
                        background-color: white;

                    }
                        h1 span .underline:before {
                            content: '';
                            width: 0px;
                            height: 0px;
                            position: absolute;
                            top: 0;
                            left: -10px;

                            background-color: transparent;
                            border-style: solid;
                            border-width: 5px;
                            border-color: transparent black black transparent; 
                        }
                        h1 span .underline:after {
                            content: '';
                            width: 0px;
                            height: 0px;
                            position: absolute;
                            top: 0;
                            right: -10px;

                            background-color: transparent;
                            border-style: solid;
                            border-width: 5px;
                            border-color: black transparent transparent black; 
                        }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <div class="example">
        <div class="contain">
            <h1>
                <span>Hello World</span>
                <span>Hello Human</span>
                <span>Hello Alien?</span>
                <span>No, Hello AI!</span>
            </h1>
            <div class="underline"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="contain">
            <h1>
                <span>Hello World</span>
                <span>Hello Human</span>
                <span>Hello Alien?</span>
                <span>No, Hello AI!</span>
            </h1>
            <div class="underline"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="contain">
            <h1>
                <span>Hello World</span>
                <span>Hello Human</span>
                <span>Hello Alien?</span>
                <span>No, Hello AI!</span>
            </h1>
            <div class="underline"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="contain">
            <h1>
                <span>Hello World</span>
                <span>Hello Human</span>
                <span>Hello Alien?</span>
                <span>No, Hello AI!</span>
            </h1>
            <div class="underline"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Please read questions properly before answering. A requirement is _"It needs to work on text with multiple lines."_, which this answer doesn't solve.

Comment: This does, so long as you can declare where the line breaks are using spans. Temani Afif already provided you one solution, I simply gave you another way to do it.